# Find a key in Lookup<> by value

Tags: c#

It probably is something stupendously simple but I am trying to find the key based on a matching value. In my case I made a lookup Lookup<database table, database column>. So every table can have multiple columns. Finding a column is fairly simple.

```
var myColumnId = 1234;
var myColumn= TheLookupObject.SelectMany(x => x.Key.Columns).Where(c => c.Value.Id == myColumnId ).FirstOrDefault();
```

But what if I want to retrieve the Key for the Value matched? I am bit stuck here, anyone can help me in the right direction?

**Solution proposal by NetMage helped me move forward:**

```
var IdToFind = 1234;
var columnDefinition = MyLookupObject.SelectMany(x => x.Key.Columns).Where(c => c.Value.Id == IdToFind).FirstOrDefault();
var keyDefinition = MyLookupObject.Where(x => x.Key.Columns.Contains(columnDefinition)).Select(cg => cg.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Why did you make a lookup indexed by table instead of by Column `Id`?

Comment: What's your data structure like? What is the exact type of `TheLookupObject`?

Comment: Your code won't compile (assuming "database table" means `DataTable`). Please fix it, or put in the actual C# data types.

Comment: As mentioned in my opening post, I use a C# Lookup<TKey,TElement>  (e.g. not a Dictionary, Hashtable or Datatable). 

So Lookup<Table,Column>. Let's assume both have a basic Name and Id property, nothing special.

Comment: Still wonder what the point of using `Lookup` is when you aren't actually using it as as lookup...

Comment: I am using the same object in various other locations; there it is actually more used as a lookup. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would create a new `Lookup` that maps the columns to the tables, but if not, you can do this:

```
var myTable = TheLookupObject.Where(cg => cg.Key.Columns.Contains(myColumn))
                             .Select(cg => cg.Key)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This was the key, thanks NetMage. I ended up combining both statements to get both the Key and Value based on a property value.

This now works perfectly.

var columnDefinition = all.SelectMany(x => x.Key.Columns).Where(c => c.Value.Id == column.Key).FirstOrDefault();

var keyDefinition = all.Where(x => x.Key.Columns.Contains(columnDefinition)).Select(cg => cg.Key).FirstOrDefault();